# Rename file with different text position in batch

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I am trying to rename text files with a different text position.

Example :

```
20170811191008_marie.txt --> marie_txt_20170811191008
```

I have a very basic rename batch command to rename files in loop but I am trying to find out how I can change the position of the text within the filename.

Command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do ren "%%~i" "%%~ni txt%%~xi"
```

Comment: Do the files to rename always have the same pattern, I.e. digit_alpha.txt?

Comment: Yes @SamirSadek

Comment: …and you no longer want a file extension!

Comment: @Compo Only the filename.. no extension

Comment: Worth a read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your wish

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%i in (
    'dir /b /a-d *_*.txt ^|findstr /i "^20[0-9]*_.*\.txt$"'
) do echo ren "%%i_%%j" "%%~nj_txt_%%i"
```

---

```
> SO_45673483.cmd
ren "20170811191008_marie.txt" "marie_txt_20170811191008"
```

**EDIT** forgot to mention to remove the echo in front of ren to really execute the rename once you are shure it does want you want.

Comment: Thanks!!.. This works but, can we do a mass change within the folder for multiple files? Getting a file not found when run in the same directory

Comment: That should work, the findstr will take only files beginning with `20` and numbers up to the `_` so it wouldn't reprocess already renamed files.

Comment: @LotPings Why have you added `~` to `%%~nj`, but not others?

Comment: @SteveFest The sole `~` is used to strip possible surrounding double quotes - not necessary here. I you want to use a modifier  here `~n` to strip the extension it is required.

Comment: @LotPings Correct. I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple file extensions, you could always use something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "EOL=_ Tokens=1* Delims=_" %%A In ('Where .:??????????????_*.*') Do (
    Set "fx=%%~xB"
    Ren "%%A_%%B" "%%~nB_!fx:~1!_%%A" 2>Nul)
```

*You can of course still specify `.txt` instead of `.*` but there would be no need to hard code `_txt_` into the code following it.*

Comment: Why don't you move the `setlocal` and `endlocal` out of the loop? It may sound illogical, but the process should be faster. And BTW, where's `timeout -1`?

Comment: @SteveFest, I decided to remove the pause in favour of timeout, then decided that neither was required, so removed the pause only. I don't care about speed issues, _unless writing and using a script takes longer than performing the task manually_, but have decided to do as you mentioned with the delayed expansion statement.